# Select a subset of columns (ie. filter data frame by collection of column keys)

Tags: f#, deedle

There are some examples of how to get a **single** column from a data frame like this.

```
people?Age
people.["Age"]
people.GetColumn("Countries")
```

but how can you get a subset of **multiple** columns? For example, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
people.[["age";"Countries"]]
```

or

```
people.GetColumn(["age";"Countries"])
```

and have it return a data frame with just those two columns/series. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Frame.sliceCols` is one way to do this, but you can use the slicing syntax too. The trick is to use slicing on `people.Columns` rather than directly on the frame:

```
people.Columns.[["age";"Countries"]]
```

The motivation for this is that you might want to slice the rows as well, in which case you can do `people.Rows.[ [1;3;5 ]`. If your frame has ordered row index, you can select a range and do `people.Rows.[1 .. 10]`.

Comment: Thanks. My two attempts above were aiming at this but I just couldn't seem to find the right permutation. Please do add this to your examples in the docs

Comment: Is something like this possible in C#?

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was looking for in the [frame API section](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/reference/deedle-framemodule.html). One can select multiple columns, creating a new frame by:

```
let newFrame = people |> Frame.sliceCols(["age";"Countries"])
```

I think the current documentation is great, but it might benefit by adding an example like this to the section **Manipulating data frames** of [this page](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/reference/deedle-framemodule.html).

Comment: I just updated the documentation to the latest version. Can you please have a look and see if it looks good enough now?

Comment: If no, the page is generated from the `///` comments in the file: https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/blob/master/src/Deedle/FrameModule.fs#L377-377 (and using the long comment block at the beginning of the file). If you can submit an improvement as pull request, that is very welcome!